# how to connect c# app neural network toolbox results?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to make an app where at some point I want to be able to use the results of work of neural network toolbox in matlab, how is it possible to do? I am completely new to this topic and I have no one to ask

Comment: This kind of question is way too broad for SO. You need to show you've tried something, and ask specifics

Comment: @Alex I want to ask about some tools..if it is possible to call this matlab tool as a result of clicking the button in wpf, for example

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following way.
1. In C# write results of work of neural network into file ( for example results.csv )
2. In matlab read from file ( from results.csv )

Comment: Is it possible to do vise-versa?

Comment: yes. you can write any kind of information in file, and then in C# to read it